# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): on Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, file, cpanel

I'm getting this problem after I deployed my website on cPanel. And important point is that it works perfectly on localhost and amazon-EC2 server. So before you mark this question as duplicate, please understand it throughly.

My functionality is that, when user submits a form, a php file is created on server which contain sql queries(which counts the clicks on that file) and other dynamic content related to functionality. But when that file is executed in browser,it gives warning

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'socialle_slcm'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
```

This problem occured only on cPanel. I checked for file permission. But everything is ok. Please help.

My code is

create.php (this creates the user.php file)

```
<?php
    $txt = "
        <?php
           ob_start();
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <?php
        ob_start();
        \$con=\mysqli_connect(\"localhost\",\"social\",\"sslc123\",\"socialle_slcm\");
        \$file_id = ".$file_id.";
        if (!empty(\$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {    
        \$ip = \$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty(\$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
        \$ip = \$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
        \$ip = \$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        \$date = \date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        \$result = \mysqli_query(\$con,\"SELECT  count(visitor_id) as count_ip FROM visitors where file_id = '\$file_id' and ip_address = '\$ip'\");
        while(\$row = \mysqli_fetch_array(\$result))
        {
        \$count_ip = \$row['count_ip'];
        }
        if(\$count_ip == 0)
        {
        \$result = \mysqli_query(\$con,\"INSERT INTO visitors (`file_id`,`ip_address`,`last_visited`) VALUES ('\$file_id','\$ip','\$date')\");
        }
        else
        {
        \$result = \mysqli_query(\$con,\"SELECT count FROM visitors where file_id = '$file_id' and  ip_address = '\$ip'\");
        while(\$row = \mysqli_fetch_array(\$result))
        {
        \$count = \$row['count'];
        }
        \$count++;

        \$result = mysqli_query(\$con,\"UPDATE visitors SET count = \$count,last_visited = '\$date' WHERE file_id = '\$file_id' and ip_address = '\$ip'\");
        }
        header('Location: ".$landing_page."');
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
    ";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
```

user.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
ob_start();
$con=\mysqli_connect("localhost","social","sslc123","socialle_slcm");
$file_id = 425;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {   
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$date = \date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  count(visitor_id) as count_ip FROM visitors where file_id = '$file_id' and ip_address = '$ip'");
while($row = \mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$count_ip = $row['count_ip'];
}
if($count_ip == 0)
{
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO visitors (`file_id`,`ip_address`,`last_visited`) VALUES ('$file_id','$ip','$date')");
}
else
{
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count FROM visitors where file_id = '425' and  ip_address = '$ip'");
while($row = \mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$count = $row['count'];
}
$count++;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE visitors SET count = $count,last_visited = '$date' WHERE file_id = '$file_id' and ip_address = '$ip'");
}
header('Location: http://rackinfotech.com');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly on localhost and amazon-EC2 server and giving problem on cpanel only.

Comment: Hope that isnt your real password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!!!!
Solved the problem by **removing unnecessary new lines and html code**

Thus created file contains below code and it works perfectly.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$con=\mysqli_connect("localhost","social","sslc123","socialle_slcm");
$file_id = 425;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {   
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$date = \date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  count(visitor_id) as count_ip FROM visitors where file_id = '$file_id' and ip_address = '$ip'");
while($row = \mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$count_ip = $row['count_ip'];
}
if($count_ip == 0)
{
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO visitors (`file_id`,`ip_address`,`last_visited`) VALUES ('$file_id','$ip','$date')");
}
else
{
$result = \mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count FROM visitors where file_id = '425' and  ip_address = '$ip'");
while($row = \mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$count = $row['count'];
}
$count++;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE visitors SET count = $count,last_visited = '$date' WHERE file_id = '$file_id' and ip_address = '$ip'");
}
header('Location: http://rackinfotech.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the IP address of the server instead of using `localhost`. Also, is the version of MySQL different for your Amazon server compared to the one using cPanel?

Comment: version of mysql is not problem. Because other queries in website work properly. I'll try using ip address of server.